# Move a directory to trash

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

is it possible to move a entire directory to trash (like a file QFile::moveToTrash)?
There is a folder with a lot of files, which would make it confusing when moving each individual file to the trash.

Edit:

```
        // "backup" is a folder in the application directory
        //QDir("backup").removeRecursively();
        QFile::moveToTrash("backup");
        ui->btnDeleteAllBackups->setEnabled(false);
        refreshDiskUsage();
        qInfo().noquote() << "Deleted backups";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. Just use `QFile::moveToTrash(path_to_dir);` to your directory, the same way as you would do it with a file. This one line will move the whole directory with all its contents to trash. This works with Qt 5.15.2. There were some bugs in some older versions of Qt (mostly on Linux) so make sure you have the most recent version possible.

Beware however that some drives (flash disks) usually do not support trash bin and the content will be deleted permanently.

Comment: After running, the folder is not in the trash, but deleted entirely (I have the latest Qt version).

Comment: Did you delete it from a disk which has trash bin? On which Windows you are?

Comment: Yes, my disk has a trash bin. I've Windows 10. `QFile::moveToTrash` with files works.

Comment: On my computer everything works. Have a look at this code https://pastebin.com/3dz4pHbX It outputs `true`, `true`, `true` for me. And when I open Recycle bin, I can see it is there, and when I click Restore, then it is restored correctly including the contained file.

Comment: If you retest everything twice on your computer and it still does not work, then please report a bug to https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Btw. you should show your code... maybe there is some bug in your code.

Comment: See edit of first post. Should it be an absolute path?

Comment: I tried that with relative paths and it works for me too. Btw. what value does your call to `moveToTrash()` return? `true` or `false`?

Comment: Well, it returns true. I tested it again and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is [QDir::removeRecursively](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#removeRecursively).

> Removes the directory, including all its contents.
>
> Returns true if successful, otherwise false.

Keep in mind that this does only report wether the operation was successful or not. Deleting the content separately would give you the opportunity to show a progress dialog to the user and report errors more specific.

Comment: This is the function I currently use. But it removes the directory "forever", I want to move the directory / folder to the windows trash. Maybe there's a path where the trash exists?